# Regex with optional group at the end

Tags: regex

I have the following strings:

```
/api/1.0/clients/0/
/clients/
/clients/0/
/clients/0/delete
```

And I want to match these out of them:

```
/clients/0/
/clients/
/clients/0/
/clients/0/
```

My current regex is `\/clients\/(?:\d*)`, which matches these:

```
/clients/0
/clients/
/clients/0
/clients/0
```

The `/` is missing.

Comment: Why the non-capturing group around the capturing group?

Comment: chris85 would be better, but that would not match, if there is anything behind it.

Comment: Patrick Haugh edited it.

Comment: Maybe [`\/clients\/(?:\d+\/)?`](https://regex101.com/r/CgLVh0/1)? If there are digits *and* `/` or if there is none of them, there will be a match.

Comment: @chris85 oh wait. I read $ not ?. my fault. That regex would work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
\/clients\/(?:\d+\/)?
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/sYLNQH/2)**

Comment: BTW, this `\/clients\/(?:\d*\/)?` will also match `/clients//`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, lol, good catch. Thanks for point that. Fixed with `\d+`